# Is $(a,\infty] = \bigcup(r_i,\infty]$?

Tags: real-analysis

For any $a$ in $\mathbb R$ (the extended real number set) ,can you choose $r_i$ in $\mathbb Q$ (rational numbers set) such that $(a,\infty] = \bigcup(r_i,\infty]$ for $i=1$ to $\infty$ ? If yes, please explain , thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What is $(r_1, \infty] \cup (r_2, \infty]$ where $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $r_1 < r_2$?

Comment: Well, I guess, since there are many $r_i$ , I need to some how choose $r_i$ getting close to a, as much as I can. and $r_i$ > a. But I have a hard time to put those words in math symbol. for your question, I will have $(r_1,\infty]$

Comment: Correct. What you want to use is the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The density of Q in R says that , for any $r_1$ and $r_2$ in Q, I can find an irrational d, in between. I still don't see how dose this work ?

Comment: That's not the definition, otherwise $\{0, 1\}$ would be a dense set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I was taught like that in my advanced calculus class. I have just searched online, all I see is definition in a topological space, which I can't understand since I never had topology before.

Comment: I think you need to check the definition again. As I pointed out, the definition, as you stated it, is incorrect.

Comment: The correct definition is that for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$, if $a<b$ then there exists $r\in\mathbb Q$ such that $a<r<b$.  It says the rationals are dense in the reals, NOT that the reals are dense in the rationals.  The latter would be silly because you could just use the average of $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: I am getting confused now, http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52417.html , that is the website that said r1<d<r2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the intervals 
$$
I_n=\left(a,a+\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
for $n\geq 1$. By the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, you can find $r_n\in I_n$. So $|a-r_n|<1/n$.

You can verify $(a,\infty]=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}(r_n,\infty]$. The containment $\supseteq$ is immediate. Conversely, choose $b\in (a,\infty]$. You know $|a-b|>0$. So there exists large enough $n$ such that $0<1/n<|a-b|$. Then convince yourself $b\in(r_n,\infty]$. This gives the reverse containment.